# select count, group by and having optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```
SELECT
    t2.counter_id, 
    t2.hash_counter,
    count(1) AS cnt
FROM
    table1 t1
RIGHT JOIN
    table2 t2 USING(counter_id)
WHERE
    t2.hash_id = 973
GROUP BY
    t1.counter_id 
HAVING
    cnt < 8000
```

Here are the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `platform` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `edition` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'us',
  `counter_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `counter_id` (`counter_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `counter_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hash_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hash_counter` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`counter_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `counter_key` (`hash_id`,`hash_counter`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

The "EXPLAIN" shows "Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort" for table t2. Is there any way to get rid off temporary/filesort ? or any other ideas about optimizing this guy.

Comment: `t1` isn't doing anything useful in this query. Can you eliminate it?

Comment: No, I can't. One unique key from table2 has many rows in table1. I need to get all the rows from table2 (for specific hash_id) associated with table1 that has less than 8000 rows within unique key from table1. Let's say table1 is "people" and table2 is "houses". They both have house_id field. I need to get all the houses that have less than 3 tenants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment above gives more insight into what you want. It is always better to explain more about what you are trying to achieve - just looking at the non-working SQL leads people down the wrong path.

So, you want to know which `table2` rows have < 8000 `table1` rows?
Why not this:

```
 select *
 from table2 as t2  
 where hash_id = 973
 and   8000 < (select count(*) from table1 as t1 where t1.counter_id = t2.counter_id)
 ;
```